# How is the ODE being solved in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, ode

My prof. made two codes while doing an ODE

```
function xdot= code(t,x);
A=[-.5 0; 1 0];
B=[1 ; 0];
K=[1.5 1];
U=-K*x;
xdot=A*x+B*U; `
```

and the second one was

```
[t,x]=ode23('code',[0 10],[1 1 ]');
figure(1);
plot(t,x);
grid
```

I am not sure why he is doing it like this ?
This is what I am trying to do. Which seems to give many error.

```
function xdot= code3(t,x)
A=[-.5 0; 1 0];
B=[1 ; 0];
K=[1.5 1];
tspan=[0 10];
y0=[1 1];
U=-K*x;
[t,x]=ode23(@(t,x),U=-K*x;,tspan,y0);
xdot=A*x+B*U;

figure(1);
plot(t,x);
grid
```

> code3
>   Error: File: code3.m Line: 8 Column: 19
>   Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

What is asked in this code is to form an open loop. **A B** being variable **K** is calculated and the model is **U** . The two code when are in separate script file and the second one is run,the output is as desired. I tried to merge both the script file and I can't really get it. Also,I am not able how the code is working?

Comment: I think it is the anonymous function in that line (the comma after `x)`).  Try moving it to another line like [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-a-function-to-another-function.html).

Comment: you're trying to declare a statement in ode23 after the anonymous function.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but that is not valid MATLAB syntax. If you want help, please explain what you were trying to do here. Is it just avoiding the `code` function being in a separate file?

Comment: The *error* is because of the semi-colon (terminating the line prematurely) in `U=-K*x;`, but then that line has other syntax issues (you shouldn't have a comma after `@(t,x)` and your function isn't `t` dependent anyway). The *problem* is unclear because, as Cris says, you've not stated what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: What was asked was to form an Open Loop in Linear model. When the two code(upper ones) are running the output was as desired. But when I tried to write the code in one script file I am not able to. -Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script file, the first line of the script file is called if it is a function declaration, and that usually with no arguments.

In your case you can avoid that by arranging the two code pieces in the reverse order, first the main routine and after that the function declaration. Upon loading the function declarations in the script are parsed first. Thus putting the following in one file should work (please report error messages if there are any)

```
[t,x]=ode23(@code,[0 10],[1 1 ]');
figure(1);
plot(t,x);
grid

function xdot= code(t,x);
  A=[-.5 0; 1 0];
  B=[1 ; 0];
  K=[1.5 1];
  U=-K*x;
  xdot=A*x+B*U; `
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It gives me my output !